# Embedded Derby with JPA: No Persistence Provider for EntityManager Named

Tags: eclipse, jpa, derby

Yet Another. After 3.5 hours, I turn to stackoverflow to see if anyone can figure out why this error is occurring.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named derby
```

The complete exception backtrace is as follows

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named derby
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at mmis.mars.irs.mec.batch.DerbyTest.setup(DerbyTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The following jars are referenced. These are JPA, eclipselink, derby, and derbyclient. I do not think that derbyclient is needed, but I included it per another post about embedded derby with eclipselink.

- javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
- eclipselink.jar
- derby.jar
- derbyclient.jar

The following is the persistence.xml file. It is placed inside of the META-INF folder, which is in the root directory of the project. The META-INF folder is added as a source folder to the project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="derby" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <class>JPA_class1</class>
            <class>JPA_class2</class>
            <class>JPA_class3</class>
            <class>JPA_class4</class>

            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:thedb;create=true" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

META-INF inclusion

- Included: (All)
- Excluded: (None)
- Native library location: (None)
- Ignore optional compile problems: (No)

As per other posts, the provider tag is not required.

I tried including each of the provider tags in the correct spot. Neither worked.

```
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

The following is what I tried with provider tag.

```
<persistence-unit name="derby" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and

```
<persistence-unit name="derby" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am currently running it within a JUnit test within the "test" folder, which is in the root directory and also included as a source folder. The JUnit test is failing with the following error.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named derby
```

The following is the line of code that is causing the error.

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("derby").createEntityManager();
```

Comment: You definitely don't need derbyclient.jar because you are using the Derby EmbeddedDriver and the Derby embedded JDBC Connection URL syntax. Can you provide the complete exception backtrace, not just the one line summary?

Comment: I have added the complete backtrace. Thank you ^_^.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying a `provider` tag in your `persistence-unit`? I'm not sure what "other posts" have told you that it is not required. The only thing I see is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jpa.htm#GSDVG00138 which says there are other preconditions you must meet to omit the `provider` tag.

Comment: I had tried using provider tags, yes. Neither of them resolved the error. I have edited the post to show what I tried with the provider tag to illustrate that I placed the provider tag in the correct area.

Comment: provider is not required if there is a single JPA provider in the CLASSPATH (is there?). And setting it to OpenJPA when using EclipseLink (your first attempt) would never work since that is a different JPA provider (which isn't present presumably).

Comment: There are two persistence units within the xml file, one for Oracle and one for derby. I'll just keep the provider in there. However, as mentioned before, the error is still present with the provider ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the JPA persistence.xml file is named and located in "src/META-INF/persistence.xml" in the project folder.  It is possible JPA cannot find the Persistence Unit due to incorrect path file name or incorrect path name for the persistence.xml file.